# Magento 2: how to stop process of php bin/magento setup:backup --db

Tags: magento2

I already execute below command :

```
php bin/magento setup:backup --db
```

my db is too large so it will in progress mode. but now i don't need to backup file so how can i stop without interrupt my site ?

any idea please share

Answer (score 0):

You can kill the process that runs the php command.
If you use linux run:

```
ps aux | less
```

to see the processes and the PIDs. After run:

```
 kill [PID]
```

to kill the process with the [PID] you want.

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer to one posted already except a bit easier/clearer

`ps -aux | grep 'php bin/magento'`

`kill -9 [PID]`

Alternatively if you still had the console window open you can use [ctrl] + [c]